# How can I stop Memgraph from writing logs on disk?

Tags: memgraphdb

I don't need Memgraph logs on my disk. I just want to view them in my terminal on the same place where I see all of the OS errors.

How can I set `stderr` to be the only place where log can be seen? I've tried to set `-log-file="/dev/null"`